# Преобразовать json to base64

Tags: python

Не могу преобразовать json в base64

```
jsonSend  = {"pres": {
        "file": i,
        "data": data
        }

b =  json.loads(s1)
base = base64.b64encode(b)
```

Ошибка the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Пробовал так

```
s1 = json.dumps(jsonSend)

b =  json.loads(jsonSend)
base = base64.b64encode(b)
```

Ошибка Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import base64

jsonSend = {"pres": {"file": 'i', "data": 'data'}}
s = json.dumps(jsonSend)
base = base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))

print(base)
```

**Источник:** [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831543/base-64-encode-a-json-variable-in-python)

Comment: TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: тут может быть проблема в том, что у меня data - байты ?